# How to sync Android Firefox with my private ownCloud?

Tags: firefox-for-android, owncloud

I have setup `Firefox 38` *(on my PC)* synchronization with my private [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) server. I just had to add `services.sync.tokenServerURI` and `services.sync.username` strings in `about:config` ([Mozilla and ownCloud](https://github.com/owncloud/mozilla_sync/blob/master/INSTALL.md)). Now I can sync everything that Firefox offers to sync with my private cloud.

How to make the same for Firefox on Android?

I added those string on Android with no success.

Comment: See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989756

Comment: @MorrisonChang Are you trying to say that it's not supported now? Some says https://www.palemoon.org/sync/ works.